# Anchor <a> tags are not working in slider

Tags: html, hyperlink, slider, anchor, bxslider

There is a slider at the top of the page.
Each slide has a layer of list and anchor tags with image tag inside.

https://www.rakuten.ne.jp/gold/yanosp-fineplay/

Here is the HTML code for the slider part.

```
<div class="slider">
    <ul class="bxslider">
        <li>
            <a href="https://item.rakuten.co.jp/yanosp-fineplay/rundayspack/" target="_blank"><img alt="ランデイズパック　リュック" src="sliderimg/rundaysslider.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://item.rakuten.co.jp/yanosp-fineplay/y002/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="sliderimg/porchn.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="https://item.rakuten.co.jp/yanosp-fineplay/p17fw-sl013/" target="_blank"><img alt="" src="sliderimg/slider13.jpg" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, each anochor tag has target="_blank" and it's supposed to open a new tab for a new page. However, clicking won't open the link, let alone a new tab. I was wondering if this has something to do with z-index or something, but what's weird is that, if you go ahead and hover each image in slider, the link still appears. I just can't figure out why this is happening, and any helps would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much.

PS - I do not think this has something to do with bxslider plugin, so please refrain from just commenting something like "Try other slider js"

Comment: Do you mean, clicking the link will open the link, but not in the new tab?

Comment: Forgive me, I failed to explain it in details. I will edit the post right now, but clicking the link won't open the link either.

Comment: The z-index is in the way. Remove it from the li element or add z-index: 60; to the a element

Comment: the click listener is captured by bxslider, are you sure you have another link that works with bxslider other than this page?

Comment: @Gerard wait how to? I can't still open the link, I think it is more event propagation problem than there is some element at top of other element :/

Comment: @Gerard I don't think z-index is the reason here. When you go over the slider, the link URL still pops up on the bottom left, which means there's nothing blocking in the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is how the bxslider.js plugin works,
When you click, the action is working on the bxslider.js plugin slidering  instead of clicking the link.

but when you alread slider to other picture, the clicking anchor action is working. try it!

sorry for poor english.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. But my other bxslider is working just fine, so I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: well, try others slider js instead.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but again, I don't think that's the case because my other bxslider is working just fine. It must be a different thing that's causing this issue.